# PyInstaller : “failed to execute script” Error

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to make an `.exe` file with PyInstaller however I'm unable to do so. The file is built and deposited in the dist folder, however when I try to run it, the error `Failed to execute script {name}` pops up.

**Here is the code that I'm using:**

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
def process_exists(process_name):
    progs = str(subprocess.check_output('tasklist'))
    if process_name in progs:
        return True
    else:
        return False
while True:
   if (process_exists("notepad.exe")==False):
       os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM myapp.exe")
   print("no")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  A possible issue is that ```taskkill``` or ```tasklist``` might not be in the path or couldn't be found by python

Comment: I suggest adding `--debug=all` flag when running the pyinstaller command, that way you can see what went wrong exactly with your program.